# How to decrypt Secure SOAP Response like SoapUI does

Tags: php, web-services, soap, soapui, ws-security

SoapUI newbie here. I am invoking this secure Soap API with SoapUI 5.3 and this is how the security header was configured in SoapUI:

1. Right click project and select `show project view`
2. Select `WS-Security Configurations` tab
3. Select `Outgoing WS-Security Configuration` tab and create a new config
4. `WSS Entries` created:Username(checked `adds a  nonce` and `adds a created` boxes and selected passwordType as `PasswordText`), Timestamp(TTL 30, checked the `Sets precision of timestamp to milliseconds` box)

When sending my SOAP request, Auth type is `Basic` and selected the above configuration.

The SOAP request header now looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security
            xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
            xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsu:Timestamp
                wsu:Id="TS-68AE03334F6A9DBDDC150599839319940">
                <wsu:Created>
                    2017-09-21T12:53:13.199Z
                    </wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>
                    2017-09-21T12:53:43.199Z
                    </wsu:Expires>
                </wsu:Timestamp>
            <wsse:UsernameToken
                wsu:Id="UsernameToken-68AE03334F6A9DBDDC150599839319939">
                <wsse:Username>
                    username
                    </wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password
                    Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">
                    password
                    </wsse:Password>
                <wsse:Nonce
                    EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">
                    8NBStc5kqrgPWG9pj09Svw==
                    </wsse:Nonce>
                <wsu:Created>
                    2017-09-21T12:53:13.199Z
                    </wsu:Created>
                </wsse:UsernameToken>
            </wsse:Security>
        </soapenv:Header>
```

And everything works very fine in SoapUI. But ultimately, I am going to write a Java or PHP client to consume this API. There are things I want to understand:

1. `<wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-68AE03334F6A9DBDDC150599839319940">`
   The `wsu:Id` attribute for the `Timestamp` and `Username` tokens, is there any criteria or I can generate a random value for each in each request?
2. The `nonce`: Same story as 1 above. However, the encodingType is `Base64Binary`. My understanding is that `nonce` is a random value, unique for each request to fight off replay attacks. Putting the encodingType in mind, how do I consistently create a good one from my php/Java client? When I base64decode the value generated by SoapUI, it still comes back as binary, I expected a String, what is SoapUI doing here??
3. The response in SoapUI is XML, but when I send the request from PHP, I receive either a binary response or just this:
   `bool(false)`
   So how does SoapUI convert the response to plain XML and how can I do the same in my code??
   Here is my PHP test script which has worked for me like a charm with other Soap APIs:

   ```
   <?php
   $soap = '<soapenv:Envelope
       xmlns:ns="http://soap.crmapi.util.redknee.com/common/xsd/2011/05"
       xmlns:ns1="http://soap.crmapi.util.redknee.com/common/xsd/2008/08"
       xmlns:ns2="http://soap.crmapi.util.redknee.com/subscriptions/xsd/2011/01"
       xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
       xmlns:sub="http://soap.crmapi.util.redknee.com/subscriptions/xsd/Subscriptions-v2.0">
       <soapenv:Header>
           <wsse:Security
               xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
               xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
               <wsu:Timestamp
                   wsu:Id="TS-68AE03334F6A9DBDDC150599839319940">
                   <wsu:Created>
                       2017-09-21T12:53:13.199Z
                       </wsu:Created>
                   <wsu:Expires>
                       2017-09-21T12:53:43.199Z
                       </wsu:Expires>
                   </wsu:Timestamp>
               <wsse:UsernameToken
                   wsu:Id="UsernameToken-68AE03334F6A9DBDDC150599839319939">
                   <wsse:Username>
                       username
                       </wsse:Username>
                   <wsse:Password
                       Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">
                       password#
                       </wsse:Password>
                   <wsse:Nonce
                       EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">
                       8NBStc5kqrgPWG9pj09Svw==
                       </wsse:Nonce>
                   <wsu:Created>
                       2017-09-21T12:53:13.199Z
                       </wsu:Created>
                   </wsse:UsernameToken>
               </wsse:Security>
           </soapenv:Header>
       <soapenv:Body>
           <sub:methodName>
               <sub:header>
                   </sub:header>
               <sub:subscriptionRef>
                   <ns2:mobileNumber>
                       256723009772
                       </ns2:mobileNumber>
                   <ns2:spid>
                       10
                       </ns2:spid>
                   </sub:subscriptionRef>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               </sub:methodName>
           </soapenv:Body>
       </soapenv:Envelope>';
   $header = array(
   'Connection: Keep-Alive',
   'Content-Length: ' . strlen($soap),
   'SOAPAction:urn:methodName',
   'Host:IP:Port'
   );
       $url = 'https://ip:port/services/SubscriptionService/';
   $ch = curl_init($url); // LIVE
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $soap);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5000);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

   $result = curl_exec($ch);
   echo "\nResult\n$result\n";
   var_dump($result);
   ```